# How to read Json in Node-Red

Tags: json, parsing, node-red

I would like to ask for a help with reading JSON format from a device in Node-Red. I succesfully made to read the JSON content in Python, but applying the same strategy in Node-Red does not yield a success.

I tried several approches.

1. Use JSON node, it reports

   > Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
2. I tried the function node

```
    var str = JSON.stringify(msg.payload);
    var data = JSON.parse(str);
    // var Temp1 = data["Monitor"]["S"]["S1"]["item1"]["value"];
    msg.payload = data["Monitor"]["S"]["S1"]["item1"]["value"];
    return msg, data;
```

And Node-red reports:
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'S')

To read the Json from the device I use HTTP get

```
{
    "Monitor": {
        "DeviceInfo": {
            "DeviceName": "TCW241",
            "HostName": "TCW241",
            "ID": "5C:32:C5:00:9E:C2",
            "FwVer": "TCW241-v1.240",
            "MnfInfo": "www.teracomsystems.com",
            "SysContact": "Petr",
            "SysName": "Garaze Relay",
            "SysLocation": "Garaze Anglie"
        },
        "S": {
            "S1": {
                "description": "Garaz",
                "id": "28245C75D0013C29",
                "item1": {
                    "value": "9.4",
                    "unit": "°C",
                    "alarm": "0",
                    "min": "-40.0",
                    "max": "85.0",
                    "hys": "8.5"
                },
                "item2": {
                    "value": "---",
                    "unit": "---",
                    "alarm": "0",
                    "min": "---",
                    "max": "---",
                    "hys": "---"...
```

Comment: Why do you convert it to a string and back to a JavaScript object in the Function node? Assuming you have configured the http-request node properly it will have already parsed the payload to an object, there should be no need to convert it again (look at the "Return" option on the http-request node). If that is raising an error then the content is not a valid JSON object.

Comment: Also once the debug sidebar shows an object (not a string) you can click to get the correct JSON Path to that value.

Comment: Hi hardillb, I agree with your answer. the problem is http get response and/ or format of the JSON. The output of the HTTp get is as I attached earlier. I do not see any problem with it. It does not want to parse. Here is attached only part but even in whole I do not see problem. Apart that it is formated not a line. And maybe some of the charactter migth be incompatible.

Comment: Without the full object or access to the same API endpoint there isn't anything else we can say here.

Comment: I would like to add fullobject it is only 11k but there is no way how I can attach it and I can not put 10000+ characters here.

Comment: I found the solution from other forum. There is some bug in Node red. Even though the object is correct Node red refuse to read it. Using a string node and remove white spaces it foxes the issue. Thank you for helping. regards